# Website looks awful in IE but great in Firefox - IE not reading javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a template for a website and it looks great on safari and firefox.  However, on internet explorer it is a big mess and it seems as though the javascript is being ignored.  Can someone please help me?  I am not familiar with javascript, but I can edit parts of it if necessary.  The website is at www.erindalesystems.com/ES

I also have the javascript code in the ES folder where the home page is.

Comment: Hi Suzanne. I don't think you're going to get an answer. You need to be more specific about your problem, what code isn't working and provide a snippet. Please see the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq on how to ask questions. Incidently the page renders fine in IE8 with no errors. Whether it looks how you want it to I've no idea.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of your CSS looks to be using proprietary mozilla extensions e.g.:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EE3C09, #B90909);
```

Everything prefixed with -moz will be ignored by most IE instances.

I'd replace these with their CSS3 equivalents, and give a little time to testing in IE (although it pains me to say this).

Comment: hmmm...would you know of a website that can give me the CSS3 equivalent to replace out the -moz- info?  Thanks

Comment: This page gives a list of all extensions: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions.
It gives alternatives supported by other browsers (or indicates if if an extension is obsolete).

Comment: thanks so much!  Of course this was not going to be easy - haha!...thanks again!

Comment: @Suzanne You should accept his answer as the correct answer if it helped you out.  Click the checkmark under the upvotes of the answer.